# Query using RAND but following a defined structure

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem and I would like to know how to solve it creating a query on MySQL.

Check out those two tables:

[image]

[image]

I need to follow a structure to show the results I want. It is like a randon inside a randon. For example, I want to randomize each section, but ids 1 to 3 must be together and then randomize too.

[image]

How would be a query to get such results?

Comment: thanks for your time to help me.. the answer is also interesting and simple I could say.. take a look, the answer is what I needed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this query:

```
select id, id_start, id_end, rand() rnd
from table2
group by id, id_start, id_end
```

you can return a random number for each of the rows of `table2`.
Join this query to `table1` and sort the result first by that random number and then by random:

```
select t1.id, t1.description
from table1 t1 
inner join (
  select id, id_start, id_end, rand() rnd
  from table2
  group by id, id_start, id_end
) t2
on t1.id between t2.id_start and t2.id_end
order by t2.rnd, rand()
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=95194037bb8fc16161e12bd56452a278).

Comment: simply perfect!!! ..thanks man, it is what I need for the problem I have =)